# Date.parse sends three extra zeroes when converting from utf-timecode

Tags: javascript

I have a variable called

```
posts_object[i].updated_time
```

It's always an utf-timecode. It seems to always send three zeroes too much. A few examples:

```
Unix            Date
1339705666000 · 2012-06-14T20:27:46+0000
1280403912000 · 2010-07-29T11:45:12+0000
1338635118000 · 2012-06-02T11:05:18+0000
```

The code:

```
postobj.created=posts_object[i].updated_time.substring(0,10);
var sortvar= (posts_object[i].updated_time);
postobj.sort=Date.parse(sortvar);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript uses timestamps in milliseconds, rather than whole seconds like timestamps are "supposed" to be. Since there are 1000 milliseconds in a second, that would explain the three extra zeroes.

Comment: I thought it was something like that. I googled utf8 date.parse javascript, but nothing came up... A bit strange...

Comment: I think it is more usual for timestamps to include the milliseconds than not. You just have to be aware what the behaviour is in whatever system you're using. (I've worked on one system where a "timestamp" was a twenty-digit string with YYYYMMDDHHmmssxxxxxx, i.e., including fractions of a second down to six decimals.)