# Reconstruct JSON Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, datetime, parsing

I need help on how to reconstruct JSON array properly. With no skill on JS, I find it's really hard to do this, even though it looks really simple task. I'm more hardware guy. :)

So, here is the data received from http API:

```
[
   {
      "ghi":491,
      "ts":"2021-07-21T07:30:00.000000Z"
   },
   {
      "ghi":422,
      "ts":"2021-07-21T08:00:00.0000000Z"
   },
   {
      "ghi":356,
      "ts":"2021-07-21T08:30:00.0000000Z"
   },
   {
      "ghi":294,
      "ts":"2021-07-21T09:00:00.0000000Z"
   },
   {
      "ghi":189,
      "ts":"2021-07-21T09:30:00.0000000Z"
   }
]
```

And, I would like to transform this to:

```
[
   {
      "ghi":491,
      "ts":"unix timestamp here"
   },
   {
      "ghi":422,
      "ts":"unix timestamp here"
   },
   {
      "ghi":356,
      "ts":"unix timestamp here"
   },
   {
      "ghi":294,
      "ts":"unix timestamp here"
   },
   {
      "ghi":189,
      "ts":"unix timestamp here"
   }
]
```

As you notice, Date.parse() won't work since there is extra 0000 before Z.
Can somebody help me to solve this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is there extra 0000 before Z?

Comment: Please share the code which you have tired. You can replace the extra `0000` using `string#replace`.

Comment: @darwin: Why do you think `Date.parse` (or `new Date`) would fail? It works just fine as far as I can see (and it should, because even with tenth of microseconds this is a valid ISO8610 date)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the string notation to the `new Date()` constructor, and then get the timestamp via [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime):

```js
const input = [{"ghi":491,"ts":"2021-07-21T07:30:00.000000Z"},{"ghi":422,"ts":"2021-07-21T08:00:00.0000000Z"},{"ghi":356,"ts":"2021-07-21T08:30:00.0000000Z"},{"ghi":294,"ts":"2021-07-21T09:00:00.0000000Z"},{"ghi":189,"ts":"2021-07-21T09:30:00.0000000Z"}];

const output = input.map(i => {
  i.ts = new Date(i.ts).getTime();
  return i;
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Ok, so I didn't see the last sentence in your question before my answer. That does actually the same as `Date.parse()`, but as far as I can see it seems to be working as intended?

Comment: Whoaaaa... it works.... Thank you very much for your help. I've spent whole day to figure this out.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Feel free to upvote and/or mark as accepted as you see fit!

Answer (score 0):

Date.parse seems working well. If you are worried about extra zeros in the timestamp (not before Z) please checkout this post [Date.parse sends three extra zeroes when converting from utf-timecode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067541/date-parse-sends-three-extra-zeroes-when-converting-from-utf-timecode)

And you can use this

```js
arr = arr.map((e) => {
    e.ts = Date.parse(e.ts) / 1000
    return e
})
```

if not works anyway use replace

```js
arr = arr.map((e) => {
    e.ts = Date.parse(e.ts.replace("0000Z", "Z")) / 1000
    return e
})
```

also you can use `new Date().getTime()` for getting timestamp

```js
arr = arr.map((e) => {
    e.ts = new Date(e.ts).getTime() / 1000
    return e
})
```